# Java - series of async calls, but have to wait for a response of each async call before proceeding

Tags: java, asynchronous

The existing flow for single async call is as follows:
Make a call to an internal java service that sends the message based call.
At this point, that process is done.
An observer pattern has been implemented to be called when a response (message based) comes back to the java service.
The onResponse method is called and completion of the response should happen.

Edited to give more specifics:
I have tested with CountDownLatch and Phaser to get both of these scenarios working where my main thread is responsible for spawning off the parallel thread async call.  The parallel thread completes, and the main thread waits to be notified that the response from the async call has been received.  If the response signifies a success, move on to the next parallel call, and so on.  Here is an example of Phaser that worked well.  Question is, am I on the right path, or is there something easier/better?

```
main thread:
    new Phaser(1);
    for (iteration of number of request objects received){
        create new thread, call serviceMethod.
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance;  //waits for arrival of registered party 

        if phaser.isTerminated
            stop processing this request;
    }



serviceMethod(){
    phaser.register
    perform call
}


onResponse(){
    if SUCCESS  
        phaser.arriveAndDeregister();  //main thread should continue on to 
                       next call
    else
        phaser.forceTermination
}
```

Comment: a good answer will depend a whole lot on the details of how you are making the call, how you are listening, the context and limitations of your situation, etc.;  *show us* so that we can help

Comment: Are the async calls dependent on each other? If so, then that's very important to the nature of the question.

Comment: Yes.  I cannot make the next async call until I get the response from the previous one.

Comment: Please provide us some code context.

Comment: thanks for that additional detail, but it's still far too abstract to provide a concrete answer;  the only thing anyone could say at this point is "structure your code so that the next async call does not go out until the previous one yields a result", but I bet you knew that already;  what I meant by "*show us*" is exactly what @dev said :  "Please provide us some code context."

Comment: ... also, per SO best practices, show us *what you have tried*, and *why* you think what you have tried isn't working

Answer (score 1):

My comments on your question notwithstanding, I'll offer an answer, because I believe I can give you a different sort of answer without seeing any of your code:

By *definition* an asynchronous call is one where the caller does not block waiting for a response.  So if you have a requirement to wait for a response, then you can avoid the problem you are describing by making a series of synchronous calls instead.

Again, paraphrasing a line from your question just a bit: "The process should be that I make the call, but wait for the response before triggering the next call." *describes* a synchronous calling scenario.  In that sense, I suspect you are approaching the problem from the wrong direction.